# D3: Rotating labels in Bi-Level Partition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 and javascript to create a BiLevel Partition following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/vpletzke/c5716da6a021005e7167a9504c6849b2). The labels in the left side of the diagram are upside down, and I was trying to rotate them, but I've not been successful yet.

I found numerous cases of people with the same problem, but using Sunburst. Also tried to implement those solutions, but I'm still unable to solve this problem.

```
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

/*var margin = {top: 350, right: 480, bottom: 350, left: 480},
radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 10;*/

var width = 1200,
height = 1200,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

function filter_min_arc_size_text(d, i) {return (d.dx*d.depth*radius/3)>14};

var hue = d3.scale.category10();

var luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
.domain([0, 1e6])
.clamp(true)
.range([90, 20]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); })
.size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
.endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx - .01 / (d.depth + .5); })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return radius / 3 * (d.depth + 1) - 1; });

//Tooltip description
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("id", "tooltip")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "10")
.style("opacity", 0);

function format_number(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function format_description(d) {
  var description = d.description;
  return  /* '<b>' + d.name  + '</b></br>'+*/ d.description + '<br> (' + format_number(d.value) + ')';
}

function computeTextRotation(d) {
  var ang = ((d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180;
  return (ang > 90) ? 180 + ang : ang;
}

function mouseOverArc(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")

  tooltip.html(format_description(d));
  return tooltip.transition()
  .duration(50)
  .style("opacity", 0.9);
}

function mouseOutArc(){
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke","")
  return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
}

function mouseMoveArc (d) {
  return tooltip
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
}

var root_ = null;
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  // Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
  // Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
  // and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.

  partition
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .nodes(root)
  .forEach(function(d) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.sum = d.value;
    d.key = key(d);
    d.fill = fill(d);
  });

  // Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
  partition
  .children(function(d, depth) { return depth < 2 ? d._children : null; })
  .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });

  var center = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", radius / 3)
  .on("click", zoomOut);

  center.append("title")
  .text("zoom out");

  var partitioned_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(partitioned_data)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
  .each(function(d) { this._current = updateArc(d); })
  .on("click", zoomIn)
  .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
  .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
  .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);


  var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(partitioned_data)
  .enter().append("text")
  .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
  .attr("dx", "6") // margin
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
  .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})

  function zoomIn(p) {
    if (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
    if (!p.children) return;
    zoom(p, p);
  }

  function zoomOut(p) {
    if (!p.parent) return;
    zoom(p.parent, p);
  }

  // Zoom to the specified new root.
  function zoom(root, p) {
    if (document.documentElement.__transition__) return;

    // Rescale outside angles to match the new layout.
    var enterArc,
    exitArc,
    outsideAngle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

    function insideArc(d) {
      return p.key > d.key
      ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 0, dx: 0} : p.key < d.key
      ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 2 * Math.PI, dx: 0}
      : {depth: 0, x: 0, dx: 2 * Math.PI};
    }

    function outsideArc(d) {
      return {depth: d.depth + 1, x: outsideAngle(d.x), dx: outsideAngle(d.x + d.dx) - outsideAngle(d.x)};
    }

    center.datum(root);

    // When zooming in, arcs enter from the outside and exit to the inside.
    // Entering outside arcs start from the old layout.
    if (root === p) enterArc = outsideArc, exitArc = insideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

    var new_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

    path = path.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; });

    // When zooming out, arcs enter from the inside and exit to the outside.
    // Exiting outside arcs transition to the new layout.
    if (root !== p) enterArc = insideArc, exitArc = outsideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

    d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function() {
      path.exit().transition()
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
      .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d)); })
      .remove();

      path.enter().append("path")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
      .on("click", zoomIn)
      .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
      .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
      .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
      .each(function(d) { this._current = enterArc(d); });


      path.transition()
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });



    });


    texts = texts.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; })

    texts.exit()
    .remove()
    texts.enter()
    .append("text")

    texts.style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
    .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
    .transition().delay(750).style("opacity", 1)


  }
});

function key(d) {
  var k = [], p = d;
  while (p.depth) k.push(p.name), p = p.parent;
  return k.reverse().join(".");
}

function fill(d) {
  var p = d;
  while (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
  var c = d3.lab(hue(p.name));
  c.l = luminance(d.sum);
  return c;
}

function arcTween(b) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, b);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function updateArc(d) {
  return {depth: d.depth, x: d.x, dx: d.dx};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

</script>
```

The problem I have is that it is only showing the right half of the Partition.

Comment: Please try to provide a sorter, easier to comprehend code sample that demonstrates the problem

Comment: In this link you can see the code working http://plnkr.co/edit/qiA5BD81asx9khqmNwbZ?p=preview.